# Is the ratio of the side and at least one diagonal of a rhombus always irrational?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The ratio between the side of a square $ c = 1 $ and its diagonal is $ \frac 1 { \sqrt 2 } $; a square is a type of rhombus.

The ratio between the side $ c = 1 $ of a rhombus, with angle $ a = \frac \pi 3 $ and its longest diagonal $ AC $ is $ \frac c {AC} = \frac 1 { \sqrt 3 } $, while the other diagonal $ BD = 1 $.

What is the equation for the lengths of the diagonals of a rhombus of side $1$?
Is the ratio of the side and at least one diagonal of a rhombus always irrational? (i.e. not an exact fraction)

Comment: $ 2 \cos (\alpha / 2 )  $ and $ 2 \sin (\alpha / 2 )  $ with ratio $  \cot (\alpha / 2 )  $ – is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you, this is 1/2 of the answer I needed

Comment: Imagine a smooth transition from a square to a nearly flat rhombus. You can achieve any ratio you want between 1/2 and infinity.

Comment: @BradyGilg yes you are right, but this does not answer my question: take the two diagonals AC and BD that show up for every case, is at least one of the ratio to the side AB/AC or AB/BD always irrational? This was the question. Answered by egreg

Comment: I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $2\alpha$ is the one of the angles in the rhombus and we take the side as the unit of measure, then the ratios you're interested in are $\sin\alpha$ and $\cos\alpha$.

Can they be both rational? Note that
$$
\sin\alpha=\frac{2\tan(\alpha/2)}{1+\tan^2(\alpha/2)},
\qquad
\cos\alpha=\frac{1-\tan^2(\alpha/2)}{1+\tan^2(\alpha/2)},
\qquad
\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{\sin\alpha}{1+\cos\alpha}
$$
so that $\sin\alpha$ and $\cos\alpha$ are both rational if and only if $\tan(\alpha/2)$ is rational.

Since $\alpha$ can be any angle satisfying $0<\alpha<\pi/2$, $\tan(\alpha/2)$ can assume any value between $0$ and $1$, among which there are infinitely many rational numbers.

You can try and prove that choices of $\alpha=2\arctan r$, where $0<r<1$ and $r$ is rational, are in one-to-one correspondence with the primitive Pythagorean triples.

Comment: Did you not mean $ \frac 1 { 2 \sin \alpha } $ rather than $ \frac 1 2 \sin \alpha $ (etc.)?

Comment: @PJTraill No, they are actually without the $1/2$ factor (removed now)

Answer (score 61):

No, you can make a rhombus out of four identical Pythagorean right triangles, such as (3, 4, 5).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; the long diagonal of that rhombus is sqrt(97) units long.

Comment: @Robyn What are you talking about? The rhombus has sides $(5, 5, 5, 5)$ and its two diagonals have lengths $8$ and $6$ respectively. Of course you scale everything to a fifth of those values, so that the rhombus has side $1$ and the diagonals have sides $8/5$ and $6/5$.

Comment: Oh, I see! You're right. I was thinking of the rhombus with sides (5,6,5,6) that could be made by arranging the same 4 triangles in a different way.

Comment: @Robyn A rhombus is a special kind of parallelogram that has all sides of equal length. the shape you were thinking of was a parallelogram, but not a rhombus.

Comment: Thank you, this is 1/2 of the answer I needed

Comment: Short solution.